# Error Function limes

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, special-functions

How can i calculate
$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}{erf(n)} $ with $erf(z) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^z e^{-z^{2}} \mathrm{d}z$? I know it's something like 0,84.
And i see that only the first terms are important because $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}{erf(n)}=1$

Comment: By 'limes', did you mean '$\lim$s'? I suppose you don't just want to calculate it, but calculate it efficiently?

Comment: i want to know if there is a different way than just calculating erf(1)*erf(2)*erf(3)*erf(4)...

Comment: What you want is not clear: a closed form, an approximate value? Moreover, your remark on the first term is a mistake: that the limit is 1 is a necessary condition for the product to converge, but that does not mean that only the first terms matter.

Comment: for example $\prod_{n=1}^3 erf(n) = 0,8387 $ and $erf(4) = 0,99999998$, so it doesn't change the 0,8387 very much. but what would be a closed form?

Comment: Convergence is very rapid. $0.83874032043948921151864887207058844734595614546070$ 
The ISC does not recognize it.  http://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au 


Comment: Note: "limes" is the Latin term, retained in some languages, but called "limit" in English.

Comment: Ah, thanks, Gerald, that's interesting. I thought it perhaps just an mistake in plural formation.